# Is it true that the total number of souls remains constant as per Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, atma

According to Gita,is it true that the total number of souls remains constant?

Comment: If its written in the Gita, then we are no one to question it. Because it is a Shastra in itself.

Comment: Yes the number of souls don't change because souls cannot be created, they are eternal.